# Dango - How to use "setUpTestData" with TransactionTestCase

Tags: python, django

I've created a test class, which is a `TransactionTestCase` and I tried setting up the test data as so

`test.py`

```
class SomeTester(TransactionTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls) -> None:
        cls.some_data = 'stuff"
```

but when I reference `self.some_data` in test functions it says `self.some_data is not defined`. Can you not use `setUpTestData` with TransactionTestCase? This works with `TestCase` class.

Comment: Make a `super()...` call.

Answer (score -2):

hope this will help someone

The best way that I found is to use setUp instaed of setUpTestData like this

```
class SomeTester(TransactionTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls) -> None:
        pass

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.some_data = 'stuff"
```